# How can I concat two characters to form another character?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an `arraylist` which has a list of characters. Now I want to append another character to a certain character from the list (not to form a String,but a character). How do I do that?

Example- Suppose my `arraylist` has the elements [E,X,Y,M,...]. Now I want to concat another character called 'X' with E.

My code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
        if (i == 1) {
            list.add(ar[i-1]+'X');
       }
     }
```

Comment: You seem to confuse arrays and `ArrayList`. These two are different things. Your example shows an array.
Please clarify what you are talking about.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: You can use [List#set(index, element)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set-int-E-) function

Comment: Please clarify what kind of Output do you want?

Comment: To concatenate you need `List<String>` instead of `List<Character>` as you can't have multiple character in a single variable of type `char`

Comment: Could you be thinking about something like this? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Æ

Answer (score 2):

> How can I concat two characters to form another character?

You can't. A character is just that: **one** character.

When you want to concat characters, you automatically, by definition create a **string** (which represents a sequence of characters).

As you already know the index you care about, a simple

```
String result = yourList.get(0) + "X";
```

should do. (iterating a list to retrieve one element at a known index is a bad idea, just get the value at the index you already know).

And note: lists and array in java start at index 0, not 1. 'E' in your example list has index 0, not 1!

Answer (score 0):

Try below code,

```
char[] ar = { 'E', 'X', 'Y', 'M' };
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
    if (i == 1) {
        list.add(String.valueOf(ar[i - 1]) + 'X');
    }
}
System.out.println(list);
```

**Output**
`[EX]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("E");
list.add("X");
list.add("Y");
list.add("M");
//Printing List
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
        {
            System.out.print(list.get(i));
        }
        System.out.println();
        //Adding Character X with E
        list.add(1, "X");
        //Printing List
        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
        {
            System.out.print(list.get(i));
        }
```

It will make the list elements as follows - {E, X, X, Y, M}

Answer (score 0):

- "char" is just a "char"!
- char holds up to 16-bits (2 bytes) of a single Unicode character.
- That means you cannot combine two chars as a "char" (Impossible!)
- Your list is qualified to hold "chars" only not "Strings".
- "String" make sense!
- You can use "StringBuilder" to concatenate two chars, but that would produce a "String", not a "char".
- My advice to you is to strengthen your conceptual knowledge of Java.